# PHP - Is it possible to test the array_map('unlink', glob('/folder/my_files--*.txt')) command by try/catch?

Tags: php, unlink, array-map

I would like to test if the function array_map('unlink', glob('...*.txt')) did not encounter an error:
ex.:

```
try { 
  array_map('unlink', glob('/folder/my_files--*.txt'));
} 
catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

In your opinion, does this code seem valid?
Thank you for your feedback !

Comment: Since [none](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) [of](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) [these](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) ever throw an exception: no.

Comment: Can I test with a boolean value? like: `$test = array_map('unlink', glob('/folder/my_files--*.txt'));`

`if( boolval($test) == false ){
// ...manage error...
}`

Comment: `array_map` returns an array of values. You'd need to test whether every value in the array is `true`. For that, `array_reduce` is actually better suited, because you can reduce to one value _while_ you iterate.

Comment: In a PHP sandbox i tested : `var_dump( boolval(array_map('unlink', glob('/folder/my_files--*.txt'))) );` this return `false`

Comment: That would be the case if `glob` returned an empty array because the path expression didn't match anything, which means `array_map` also returns an empty array, and an empty array evaluated as boolean is falsey.

Comment: I tried this into the sandbox but i'm not sure of the syntax of my code : `var_dump( array_reduce( glob('/folder/my_files--*.txt'), 'unlink', $initial = null ) );` return NULL , on both methods i have tested, try/catch return  nothing

Comment: Mmm, test the boolean value seem the best way to take ...

Comment: Or you could read my answer below for a *correct* usage of `array_reduce`…

Comment: Either delete all or none if you ask me, why leave any residue?

Answer (score 2):

No, none of these function throw an exception, so no exception will ever be caught by this code. `unlink` returns `true` or `false`, so the result of `array_map` will be an array of `true` and/or `false` values, and you need to test whether all values in the array are `true` to know whether all `unlink` operations succeeded.

For this kind of operation, [`array_reduce`](https://php.net/array_reduce) is actually the better option, as it allows you to reduce the result to a single value right while you're iterating:

```
$result = array_reduce(glob('...'), fn($res, $file) => unlink($file) && $res, true);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Something didn't get deleted!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One could return the filenames where the unlinking failed with `array_filter`:

```
$filesNotDeleted = array_filter(glob('...'), 'unlink');

if (count($filesNotDeleted) === 0) {
  echo "Everything got deleted";
} else {
  echo "The following files were not deleted:";
  print_r($filesNotDeleted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm!, in fact I'm too stupid, it doesn't matter the extension of the file, what I want is to empty the folder... Deceze's answer is very good if we want to specifically delete a type of file, among others other file types. I'm going to use DirectoryIterator:

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        unlink( $fileinfo->getFilename() );
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answers, it's late here, it helped me think!